# Move Data from SQL to Aerospike

Tags: mysql, database, aerospike

I want to transfer lot of data(>10gb) from my MySQL database to Aerospike. What is the best approach for the same? 
I know that I can dump MySQL data to CSV and then read it in Aerospike but I wanted to know if their is any other approach with smaller SLA or more secure way for it.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest would be to `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` using the necessary delimiters and line endings to make the output CSV compatible. You would then use the aerospike loader tool ([aerospike/aerospike-loader](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-loader)) to load the data into Aerospike. The tool allows you to use multiple threads to read and write in parallel, so it's quite fast.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in a one-time migration only I would recommend the CSV-Export/-Import way. If you migrate the table structure (`CREATE`-Statements) you dont have to worry about the datatypes too much.

Another way would be a script/programm/ETL-Tool connecting to mysql, read line-by-line and write line-by-line (entity-by-entity?) to aerospike. Depending on the brain you invest in such a solution you might/might not end up with a (very) slow/fast solution. imho this makes sense for a regular data exchange only.